# Add iconified links to a minimised twitter bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I am using a stock navbar from getbootstrap.com, I would like to put iconified links on a **'collapsed'** navbar.  The only way I have found is to use the "navbar-brand" class attribute like so ...

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#link1">My Brand</a>
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#link2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" aria-hidden="true"></a>
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#link3"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></a>
```

resulting in this :

[image: Screenshot of collapsed navbar with icon's]

1) Is there a specific class attribute for 'non-branded links, as I assume this method would have repercussions for visitors using assistive technology. I tried 'navbar-btn' and a regular 'button', but neither line up vertically, or look nice.

2) I would like to hide these iconified links when using the app on a laptop (if possible).  ie. use icons on mobile, menus on desktop.

This will be for a CRUD application with limited functionality, and the drop down menu is cumbersome on a phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer 1**

Yes bootstrap has class attribute for 'non-branded links it is `class="navbar-text"`.

**Answer 2**

Use bootstrap `hidden-lg` to hide these links on desktop app.

**Working example**

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
          </head>
          <body>

    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#link1">My Brand</a>
<a class="navbar-text hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm" href="#link2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" aria-hidden="true"></a>
<a class="navbar-text hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm" href="#link3"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></a>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast responce, I have marked this as the answer as it appears in the documentation : http://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.0.3/docs/css/).  However it doesn't actually work for me (tried firefox and chrome).  For some reason when I use 'hidden-lg' (or 'sm' or 'md'), the icons hide in desktop mode not in collapsed mode. ** Note it does work on the 'navbar-brand'.

Comment: I updated my snippet try this..It should hide the icons in large(desktop), medium(tablets), and small mobile devices. but it will not be hidden in xs devices.

Comment: Great, it works as long as I have 2 or more 'hidden-*' tags defined.  Thank you very much.